# How to access class member from lambda in C#?

Tags: c#

In java I can do this

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    OtherClass oc = new OtherClass();
    oc.a.run();
  }
}

public class OtherClass
{
  public int s = 3;
  public Runnable a = () -> System.out.println("s is " + s);
}
```

The output will be `s is 3`. When I try this in C# with this code

```
using System;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass m = new MyClass();
            m.a.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public int s = 3;
        public Action a = () => Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Then I get `(23:51) A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'SomeNamespace.MyClass.s'`

Comment: Why is `MyClass.a` not just a normal method? Using `Action` adds no value.

Comment: You can't use a field initializer, but if you create the delegate in the constructor explicitly it should work. However, I agree with @Dai in that it'd be better to just make it a normal method.

Comment: @Xcelled194 just moving `a` initialisation to constructor worked. Thanks